# Create dependencies between documents in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I want to create a dependency between some documents in my collection.
For example I have document A, and I want to use some fields of it in document B as a subsection. So if I change document A, the fields that are also in document B will also change.

Here's a better explanation with actual JSONs:
Here's document A

```
{ 
    "_id": ObjectId("1"),
    "value": 10,
    "name": "A_document_name",
    "owner": "some_owner"
}
```

Here's document B

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("2"),
    "description": "some_description",
    "valid": true,
    "name": "some_name",
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "A_object_name"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, what I want to happen is, if I change the name of document A, I want to see that it also changed in the items section of document B. Currently, when I change A's name, it changes only in A and B remains the same since it was created. Is it achievable in Mongo? How can I create a reference between `items` section in B with A? Do I need to change something in my document structure?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use mongoDB's [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

You you'd a unique identifier from that you can use match the documents,
e.g:
The `A` document would be:

```
{ 
    "_id": ObjectId("1"),
    "b_id": ObjectId("2"),
    "value": 10,
    "name": "A_document_name",
    "owner": "some_owner"
}
```

While the `B` document would just be:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("2"),
    "description": "some_description",
    "valid": true,
    "name": "some_name"
}
```

You'll then do an aggregate query like so:

```
db.B.aggregate([
   {
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "A",  //The collection you're getting the items from
         localField: "_id", //The local field you're using to lookup 
         foreignField: "b_id", //The field the `A` document you're using to match
         as: "items" //The name of the field that will be populated with the results
       }
  }
])
```

There's a lot more you can do with [aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) take a minute to look through the docs. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I don't think Mongoose is an option, because the project I'm working doesn't use it, and I'm not familiar with that project enough to start changing things so that I can add Mongoose. Is there a way to achieve it using only MongoDB?

Comment: I saw a mongoose tag so i assumed you wanted that implementation. Assuming you're using mongo client, yes it can be done using $lookup https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/. Do you want me to change my answer then? @keselme

Comment: sorry for the delay, I used the mongoose tag accidentally, if you can change your answer it would be great!